# Why is bar undefined in the following JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am playing around with CoffeeScript and the 'class' keyword, ended up with the following:

```
var Foo, foobar;

Foo = (function() {
  function Foo() {}

  Foo.bar = 7;

  return Foo;

})();

foobar = new Foo;

alert(foobar.bar);
```

after typing in:

```
class Foo
  @bar = 7


foobar = new Foo

alert foobar.bar
```

I kind of expected bar to retain that value but the alert pops up as `undefined`

Comment: If you're interested in JavaScript prototype and constructor functions in JavaScript I've written an introduction here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 Why the value of Foo is provided by an IIFE is because you may want to use closure values. In this case it is redundant because you don't have any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bar` is a property of `Foo` (the function), not instances it creates.

If you want `bar` on *instances*, you have two choices:

1. Set it within the constructor:

   ```
   class Foo
     constructor: () ->
       @bar = 7

   foobar = new Foo

   alert foobar.bar
   ```

   Which translates to this JavaScript:

   ```
   var Foo, foobar;

   Foo = (function() {
     function Foo() {
       this.bar = 7;
     }

     return Foo;

   })();

   foobar = new Foo;

   alert(foobar.bar);
   ```
2. Or set it on the prototype:

   ```
   class Foo
     bar: 7

   foobar = new Foo

   alert foobar.bar
   ```

   which translates to:

   ```
   var Foo, foobar;

   Foo = (function() {
     function Foo() {}

     Foo.prototype.bar = 7;

     return Foo;

   })();

   foobar = new Foo;

   alert(foobar.bar);
   ```

Comment: oh duh... I need to use `this` instead right? ...no that didn't work either

Comment: No: what you need is remedial Javascript.  If bar is a property of Foo, it would be accessible as `Foo.bar`

Comment: @GeorgeJempty: I believe he/she is looking for the CoffeeScript syntax.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty ah yes, I am not familiar with the JavaScript that CoffeeScript is writing for me... glad I found it though now I am forced to learn!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so what I am seeing here is... Foo equals a call to the function inside of it which returns the Foo function... right? so many layers @.@

Comment: @ioSamurai: I've added two options depending on what you want to do. :-)

Comment: Note that both options he's given have the same end-result.

Comment: @nzifnab: Not *quite*, but the difference isn't major.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder doesn't the `(function() { ... })();` part seem redundant if it's just setting Foo to the function Foo()? I am guessing this is one of CoffeeScripts 'safety' features?

Comment: @ioSamurai: It's so that if you add further functions to the `Foo` prototype, they get defined at the same time as `Foo`. Function *declarations* are hoisted, and so they don't occur in the step-by-step order of code, but assignments to properties on (say) `Foo.prototype` *do* occur within the step-by-step order of code. So CoffeeScript is ensuring both happen at the same time (in the step-by-step execution of the code), for instance as with [this](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20Animal%0A%20%20foo%3A%20(%40bar)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%40bar)%3B).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Foo
  constructor: ->
    @bar = 7

foobar = new Foo()
alert foobar.bar
```

The problem is that when you're at the class-level `@` is referring to `Foo`.  So in your example `Foo.bar == 7`, but it's not setting anything on instances (which you can do in the constructor).